# SecurityContextHolder returns correct user's value but Authentication object returns null

Tags: spring, security, authentication

I've used 2 login pages, 1 for users and another for admin. But I have stored admin information in memory but have fetched user's information from the database. The problem here is, when I want to use Authentication object it returns null. But SecurityContextHolder gives me the perfect value. I want to set this Authentication value globally, so that my every method can have it.

Here is my SecurityConfig class

```
// admin login class
@Configuration
@Order(1)
public class AdminAuthorization extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.antMatcher("/admin/**").authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasRole("ADMIN").and().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/adminLogin").loginProcessingUrl("/admin/dashboard").and().csrf().disable();
    }

    // for authentication
    @Autowired
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password(encoder().encode("admin")).roles("ADMIN");
    }
}

// Publisher login class
@Configuration
@Order(2)
public class PublisherAuthorization extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) {

        try {
            http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/publisher/**").hasRole("PUBLISHER")
            .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login").successForwardUrl("/publisher/welcome")
            .failureUrl("/login?error").usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password");
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    // for authentication
    @Autowired
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)  {
        try {
            auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
                    .usersByUsernameQuery("select username, password, active" + " from publisher where username=?")
                    .passwordEncoder(encoder())
                    .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username, authority " + "from authorities where username=?");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

@Bean
public static PasswordEncoder encoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

HomeController

```
@PostMapping(value = { "/welcome", "/welcome/{QuestionPageNumber}/{ArticlePageNumber}" })
public ModelAndView page(Authentication auth, @PathVariable Optional<Integer> QuestionPageNumber,
        @PathVariable Optional<Integer> ArticlePageNumber) {
    
    
    System.out.println(auth==null); //returns true
    
    //but 
    
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    
    System.out.println(authentication.getName());  //returns correct user's information
```

Now, the problem is, I don't to use this code

> SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

on every line.(I don't know the reason why!!)..
I'm unable to collect my publisher's information. Admin is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code instead of your in memory auth implementation:

```
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;

String username = "ADMIN";
String encodedPassword = new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode("admin");
List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authList = Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));
User user = new User(username, encodedPassword, authList);
auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser(user);
```